# load .doc file locally using wkwebview for a mac application

Tags: macos, xamarin, wkwebview

In my xamarin mac application, I am trying to use a wkwebview to render local files. Currently, I can get wkwebview to render .pdf files. However, .doc and .xlsx don't seem to work. The following is my relevant code:

```
NSUrl url = new NSUrl("file:///Users/xiangyu.fu/Desktop/c.pdf");
webView.LoadFileUrl(url, url);
```

this piece of code can perfectly load c.pdf file. However, when I change the file name to a .doc file(also on desktop):

```
NSUrl url = new NSUrl("file:///Users/xiangyu.fu/Desktop/k.doc");
webView.LoadFileUrl(url, url);
```

the wkwebview doesn't render any content. So am I missing something here or does wkwebview simply doesn't support rendering .doc files for mac applications?

Comment: do you have any reason to think that it should support DOCX?  I can't find any documentation to suggest that it does.

Comment: ***Assuming*** you have an Application installed that can create previews for doc/docx files and thus are able to use Finder to display a `Quick Look` preview of the file, you can embed a `QLPreviewPanel` into your app; https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartz/qlpreviewpanel